# Bonfire + Sparks

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am a newbie using [Bonfire](http://cibonfire.com) (uses [Modular Extensions - HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/)).

I want to integrate [Sparks](http://getsparks.org) to use [PhpActiveRecord](http://phpactiverecord.org) with it.

I know for a fact that it can't be done by the normal install of sparks so I followed this [tutorial](http://www.venturin.net/2011/10/29/how-to-make-ci2-work-with-hmvc-and-sparks/).

The real problem is, bonfire can't load the php-activerecord spark even though it points to the sparks directory (I have checked this).

Anyone know some tweaking?

I got an error.

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested class: phpactiverecord
```

Comment: Here is the answer from [Shawn_R](http://forums.cibonfire.com/profile/924/Shawn_R). [Link](http://forums.cibonfire.com/discussion/comment/3492#Comment_3492). It worked for me.